# next element in a List

Tags: haskell

I want to get the next element of a list in haskell like:

```
beginn = 20
next 20 = 10
next 10 = 5
next 5 = 30
next 30 = 25
next 25 = 37
next 37 = 2
next 2 = 11
next 11 = 31
next _ = -1
```

my list is : Stack  = [20,10,5,30,25,37,2,11,31]

my code is :

```
schlange  = [20,10,5,30,25,37,2,11,31]

beginn = head schlange

next y = if y `elem` schlange then [y]+1 else -1
```

but it was not correct

Answer (score 1):

first the original examples already form the definition:

```
next 20 = 10
next 10 = 5
next 5 = 30
next 30 = 25
next 25 = 37
next 37 = 2
next 2 = 11
next 11 = 31
next _ = -1
```

so you could just stick with this.

---

now if you want to use a list then maybe you should use pattern-matching here:

```
next e (x:y:ys)
  | e == x = Just y
  | otherwise = next e (y:ys)
next _ _ = Nothing
```

example:

```
λ> next 10 schlange
Just 5
λ> next 37 schlange
Just 2
```

note that this will return a `Maybe` as it can happen that the element `e` is not in the list (IMO this is better then returning `-1`)

@zeta provided a nice point-free / one-line version:

```
next e = listToMaybe . drop 1 . dropWhile (/= e)
```

you probably don't know `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe` - it's basically

```
listToMaybe [a:_] = Just a
listToMaybe []    = Nothing
```

and the function does what it says:

- drop all element that are **not** `e` from the front of the list
- then drop one more (the `e`)
- finally use `listToMaybe` to warp the first remaining element into `Just' if there is any - if not return`Nothing`

---

the reason your version is not working is that `[y]` here does not make any sense at all - `[y]` would be the singleton list of just `y` and what should a list *plus* 1 be? Why should this return a number here?

Comment: thank you for your answer @Carsten , when its possible, i want to print only x and not Just x too.

Comment: Not really time for a whole answer, but maybe you want to add `listToMaybe . drop 1 . dropWhile (/= e)`.

Comment: @Zeta I can - maybe this is a bit rough for the OP (seems he is just starting out and explaining `listToMaybe` and probably `(.)`/point-free too seems a bit much